# Identifying driving events from GPS and accelerometer data

Tags: .net, gps, neural-network, accelerometer, encog

I have an IOT device sending the following information every second from a car that is being driven:

1. Timestamp
2. GPS co-ordinates (latitude/longitude)
3. GPS bearing or Azimuth
4. Vehicle speed from GPS
5. Accelerometer readings on X, Y and Z axis.

From this information I have to identify the below driving events:

1. Braking
2. Acceleration
3. Left turn
4. Right turn

   I am trying to achieve this using a neural-network classifier from the ENCOG .net library and I am stuck at the below points:

**1. How can I format the input so that it can be fed to the neural
    network? What I have is a matrix of information with 8 columns and a
    variable number of rows:**

Eg:- A Right turn could be a matrix like below

```
Timestamp  Lattitude  Longitude   Azimuth     Speed  Xacc        Yacc        Zacc
4:57:08 PM 39.937185  -74.9530667 305.3293762 0     -0.904202607 0.33408456  0.105773433
4:57:09 PM 39.93719   -74.95307   303.1105042 0     -0.89096231  0.37406743  0.091855986
4:57:10 PM 39.9372067 -74.9530783 299.4731445 9     -0.880157497 0.395575262 0.058842602
```

Similarly a left turn could be

```
Timestamp  Lattitude  Longitude   Azimuth     Speed Xacc         Yacc        Zacc
4:57:26 PM 39.9377    -74.954015  257.7362976 18    -0.932709113 0.267096326 -0.024819622
4:57:27 PM 39.937715  -74.9540733 247.346344  18    -0.94067372  0.271379559 -0.054581382
4:57:28 PM 39.937715  -74.9541317 225.6322174 17    -0.923718111 0.293954308 -0.081829668
4:57:29 PM 39.937695  -74.9541917 213.6928406 20    -0.911598183 0.317324907 -0.128199049
4:57:30 PM 39.93766   -74.9542433 208.975174  24    -0.90052994  0.351010895 -0.121179532
4:57:31 PM 39.9376017 -74.9542833 205.9306641 28    -0.891561502 0.373537211 -0.078259489
4:57:32 PM 39.9375367 -74.9543267 206.532135  31    -0.891412538 0.389423688 -0.047274249
```

**2. What neural-network patterns and typologies could be applied to
    solve it?**

**3. What kind of training algorithm(s) could be used?**

I would appreciate it if someone could throw light on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am attempting to solve this.

1. Reduce the input matrix to contain only information that is relevant
   to identify the events. So the following columns are discarded from
   the input

   - Timestamp
   - Latitude
   - Longitude and
   - Speed

2.The reduced input would look like

```
Az      Xacc        Yacc
257.736 -0.93270911 0.267096326
247.346 -0.94067372 0.271379559
225.632 -0.92371811 0.293954308
213.693 -0.91159818 0.317324907
208.975 -0.90052994 0.351010895
205.931 -0.8915615 0.373537211
```

3.Resample the input to have at least 10 instances (rows)

- For more than 10 instances downsample using something like [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm
- For less than 10 instances upsample using any interpolation technique

4.Flatten the 10 rows to a vector containing 30 values as below

```
Az1     Xacc1       Yacc1       Az2     Xacc2       Yacc2       Az.. Xacc.. Yacc..   Az10       Xacc10      Yacc10      Target
257.736 -0.93270911 0.267096326 247.346 -0.94067372 0.271379559 ..   ..     ..       206.532    -0.89141254 0.389423688 Left
```

5.Use a Feedforward pattern like Multilayer perceptron with

- 30 input neurons
- 2 hidden layers (identify number of neurons using pruning techniques)
- 4 output neurons (using equilateral encoding: 3 for the 4 classes mentioned above and 1 extra for not-an-event)
- Activation function: Hyperbolic tangent

6.Train using Resilient propagation

Please let me know your thoughts on this solution.